# Querying Athena Views using Spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have created a view in Athena and see it in my Glue Data Catalog. I would like to access the view via Redshift Spectrum/Glue Catalog Sharing.

Per the AWS documentation:

> If you have created Athena views in the Data Catalog, then Data Catalog treats views as tables

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html

Is it possible to query Athena views via Redshift Spectrum?

Comment: Unfortunately seems not possible right now. Why do you not create a view in Redshift Spectrum instead?

Comment: With this option, the view would need to be maintained by each team we share our Glue Data Catalog with.

Comment: still not possible as of 03/17/2023...and in our case, we are unable to create regular views on Spectrum tables because we use views to achieve access mgmt (user group A can only see view A, user group B can only see view B, but both view A and view B need to query the same Spectrum table). eventually we got around it by creating materialized views

Answer (score 0):

You can create tables out of your Athena views then use the tables in redshift spectrum as external tables , this will have to be done each time you want to run the redshift query in order to re-update the table that results from the view